# Override paint method doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a rectangle on **PictureBox** without using **Paint** event of picturebox,So i override the **Onpaint** method :

```
   public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics dc = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen bPen=new Pen(Color.Blue,3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(bPen,0,0,50,50);
        }
    }
```

But the rectangle doesn't appear in first time ,but when i change the size of form using mouse my rectangle is appeared why ?!!!

Comment: I believe that OnPaint triggers before the initialization of the PictureBox

Comment: @Baldrick i did ,but doesn't work

Comment: Guys, this is OnPaint *of the form*, not of the picturebox. It is mostly independent of the picturebox's paint events. OnPaint should be implementation of Paint event of PictureBox in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you override [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/3e40ahaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of *the form* instead of `Paint` event of the PictureBox. Form's OnPaint happens, when *the form* needs repainting, and that's independent of what happens with the [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Implement OnPaint event of the PictureBox and then you will not have to create Graphics object manually - simply use one provided in the event arguments.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // No need to do that
    // pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20));
}
```

---

**Edit:** (in response to comments)

If you want to update the paintbox periodically, do the following:

1. Keep the data required to draw the scene somewhere in the form, possibly as a private field
2. Use these data to draw the scene in `Paint` event of the `PictureBox`
3. When you need to update the scene, modify the data accordingly, and then call the `Invalidate` method of the PictureBox. It will cause the `Paint` event to fire and the scene will be redrawn.

Remember though, that all calls to UI methods from the threads [has to be synchronized to the main UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (otherwise they won't work or cause problems).

Comment: ,my problem is i have a rail map that should be drawn in first time when the form is loaded ,and i have a thread that read the trains location and i have to show this trains on my map ,my problem is i have to refresh my map for every movement of trains ,

Comment: @EA: Then you have redraw (at least partially) every time you change the picture of the movements.

Comment: @EA Do it as I said and then invoke picturebox.Invalidate() in the threads (remember, that you have to forward this call to the main UI thread). By the way, have you even tried my solution?

Comment: As Spook later commented, if you call `Invalidate()` on the PictureBox, it will can the `Paint` again and redraw the entire or partial picture.

Comment: @Spook i trid ,it works ,and my shape appears ,when i use your method ,i can't move some object on picturebox ,because of that i want to use Onpaint method

Comment: Ok thanks @Spook,but what does it mean that you said **that all calls to UI methods from the threads has to be synchronized to the main UI thread **

Comment: @EA This means, that simply calling `picturebox.Invalidate()` from separate thread either won't work or will cause some problems, because UI controls are not prepared to work in multi-threaded environment. All calls to UI from separate threads should be synchronized to main UI thread using the Invoke method of the control. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you **do not** want to use the Paint event of the PictureBox. Your code wouldn't work since the form gets rendered before its containing elements.

I offer you a solution: draw on a bitmap and then insert that bitmap into the PictureBox through its **Image** public member.

```
private void loadDrawing(){
  Bitmap map = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
  var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);
  graph.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 3), 0, 0, 50, 50);
  pictureBox1.Image = map;
}
```

Let's say you want to make the Rectangle to show up upon load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadDrawing();
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea when the form gets repainted. It will not redraw then.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the paint method of the form, while you paint the `PictureBox`. That isn't how it is meant to be. The `PictureBox` will still do it's own rendering.

If you really want to do painting of the `PictureBox`, implement the [`Paint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event of the `PictureBox` or create a custom control where you draw a rectangle, and a picture.

Answer (score -1):

After you draw the form refresh the form using this :-

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics dc = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen bPen=new Pen(Color.Blue,3);
        dc.DrawRectangle(bPen,0,0,50,50);
        this.Refresh() ; 
    }
```

Comment: This is not a proper way to solve this problem, but only a workaround. Painting of the picturebox should not happen in OnPaint method *of the form*.